# Array Index Out of Bounds strange case

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I was writing a small piece of code and came across this really strange case related to array Index out of bounds exception.

I have explained it below.

1)I have an array and I am trying to assign some value at a particular index UNKNOWN to me.

```
 distanceToVerticesArr[getVertexDistanceIndex(neighbour)] = distanceToNeighbour + minDistance;
```

2) The function getVertexDistanceIndex() is as follows:

```
static int getVertexDistanceIndex(String Vertex) {
        //This method returns the index at which the distance to a particular vertex is stored in the distanceToVerticesArr

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexIndex.size(); i++) {
            if (vertexIndex.get(i).toString().equals(Vertex)) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        //index not found, hence inserting the vertex
        int j = vertexIndex.size();


        float[] temp = Arrays.copyOf(distanceToVerticesArr, distanceToVerticesArr.length + 1);

        distanceToVerticesArr = new float[temp.length];
        distanceToVerticesArr = Arrays.copyOf(temp, temp.length); //length of array = j+1
        vertexIndex.put(j, Vertex);
        return j;


    }
```

3) Now, look at the piece of code below the comment "index not found, hence inserting the index". 
If i return the value j, I get an IndexOutOfBounds exception in the call mentioned in point 1. But if I return i, I face no exception.

4)I went a bit further, I modified the code in POINT 1 as follows:

```
int VertexDistanceIndex =getVertexDistanceIndex(neighbour);
distanceToVerticesArr[VertexDistanceIndex] = distanceToNeighbour + minDistance;
```

Now, in this case, I got no exception whether I returned i or j.

5)My question is, Why this strange behaviour?

Comment: An array index out of bounds is not strange: it's a bug.

Comment: Did u read the description my friend? I repeat, did you read it carefully?

Comment: I suspect that `distanceToVerticesArr[getVertexDistanceIndex(neighbour)]` doesn't care that `distanceToVerticesArr` is changed inside your `getVertexDistanceIndex` method. So even though that variable now points to a different location in memory, Java has already said "this is where I'm looking in memory" (with the original location), and uses that - hence the index out of bounds error. However, calling the method first you've already updated your array by the time you try to access anything in it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ..Yes I suspected that. My question...why doesn't java care?

Comment: @MitchWheat Please read Anthony Grist's comment, if that makes things any clearer

Comment: @Nikhil Probably because it's already evaluated that part of the code (and decided where in memory it's going to look) before calling the method. Honestly I'd just be guessing though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I am glad, that you atleast understood my question. There are 2 people here who actually down voted it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are modifying the `distanceToVerticesArr` reference inside the `getVertexDistanceIndex` method.  So, in this case:

```
int VertexDistanceIndex =getVertexDistanceIndex(neighbour);
distanceToVerticesArr[VertexDistanceIndex] = distanceToNeighbour + minDistance;
```

when it reaches the second line, `distanceToVerticesArr` is pointing to the new array, but when you do this:

```
distanceToVerticesArr[getVertexDistanceIndex(neighbour)] = distanceToNeighbour + minDistance;
```

the value of `distanceToVerticesArr` has already been evaluated, so the old value will be used, which is of course pointing to an array which is too small.  The array pointer will be updated after the line is executed, but that is too late.  The solutions are: a) Use the first method, or b) write better code.